# sahi script for choosing and uploading a file

Tags: file-upload, automated-tests, sahi

I'm using Sahi for Test Automation of web application. I have to write a script for sahi for uploading a file. But unfortunately I don't know the way. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File upload can be a complex thing depending upon any validations you do on the upload. For a starter, you can try out the following:

**Synatx:**

```
_setFile(element, filePath [, actionURL])
```

eg:
    _setFile(_file("id"), "C:\abc\efg.jpg", "formSubmit.jsp");

If there are javascript validations on the file field, you can try this hack. Before submitting the file, change the field’s type to “text”, and then set its value. Eg.

```
// set the file
_setFile(_file("file"), "scripts/demo/uploadme.txt");
// Change the "type" attribute of file field
if (_isIE()){
_call(_file("file").outerHTML = _file("file").outerHTML.replace(/type=['"]?file['"]?/, "type=text"));
}else{
_call(_file("file").type = "text");
}
// Set the value into the textbox
_setValue(_textbox("file"), "scripts/demo/uploadme.txt");
```

This works for most of the cases. If you still get any error, you can post it here.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
_setFile(_file("id"), "C:\\abc\\efg.jpg");
```

Not sure if you need anything more complex?

Comment: i need more complex because the file upload is not converting to text box

Comment: You need more detail in your question, and some example code of where things are going wrong. It's impossible to decipher what your question is

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of [Sahi 4.3](http://sahi.co.in/sahi-pro-v-4-5-whats-new/), there is a `_setFile2` function that automatically handles js validations and does this input type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using the function `setFile2`, with internally changes the type of field to `text`

Comment: There is already an answer on here posted over two years ago that mentions that function. Do you have anything to add to that answer?